# angular animation: component is killed before trigger animation

Tags: angular, animation

I am trying to trigger an animation from the popin.component.ts that manage the view.

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output } from "@angular/core";
import {
  trigger,
  state,
  style,
  animate,
  transition
} from "@angular/animations";

@Component({
  selector: "app-popin",
  templateUrl: "./popin.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./popin.component.css"],
  animations: [
    trigger("openClose", [
      state(
        "open",
        style({
          transform: "translateY(0%)"
        })
      ),
      state(
        "closed",
        style({
          transform: "translateY(100%)"
        })
      ),
      transition("* => *", animate(500))
    ])
  ]
})
export class PopinComponent {
  @Input() isPopinOpen = false;
  @Input() isPopinAnimationActive = false;
  @Output() isPopinClosed = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  closePopin() {
    this.isPopinClosed.emit(this.isPopinAnimationActive);
  }
}
```

The parent component manage the boolean to change the state.

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  isPopinAnimationActive: boolean;
  isPopinOpen: boolean;
  animate() {
    this.isPopinOpen = true;
    this.isPopinAnimationActive = true;
  }

  closeThePopin() {
    this.isPopinOpen = false;
    this.isPopinAnimationActive = false;
  }
}
```

I have 2 problems.

1 - when I close the popin, the animation for sliding down does not work. It works only if I remove the line in comment.

```
  closeThePopin() {
    // this.isPopinOpen = false;
    this.isPopinAnimationActive = false;
  }
```

2 - It seems that angular does not read the state for transition "open" and "closed"

```
transition("open => closed", animate(500))
```

It works only when I use * like this:

```
transition("* => *", animate(500))
```

here is the codesandbox code:

https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-wilson-lqzw2?file=/src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

you need "play" with [Animations callback](https://angular.io/guide/transition-and-triggers#animation-callbacks) or use [:enter and :leave aliases](https://angular.io/guide/transition-and-triggers#enter-and-leave-aliases). Take account that if you has a `*ngIf` if is false there're no posibility to animate.

Using animations callBack is change a few your poping component

```
<div class="container" *ngIf="isPopinOpen " (click)="isPopinAnimationActive=false">
  <div class="popin" (@openClose.done)="!isPopinAnimationActive && closePopin()" 
       [@openClose]="isPopinAnimationActive ? 'open': 'closed'">
    content
  </div>
</div>
```

See that the `click()` only change the variable "isPopinAnimationActive"

In in  `(@openClose.done)`where, if isPopinAnimationActive=false execute the function "closePopin()" to emit the event.

I use the "abreviate" method `"condition && myFunction()"`. If condition is true, the function is executed, if condition is false the function is not executed.

Use :enter and :leave  allow animate components under a *ngIf

Comment: Thank you @Eliseo ! it works for me now.
And it fixed the issue regarding the transition from "open" to "closed" but it does not work from "closed" to "open"
Is it any connexion with the no use of callback methods ?
```
 transition('closed => open', animate('3750ms ease-in')),
 transition('open => closed', animate('2750ms ease-in')),
```

Answer (score 0):

In your **popin.component.html** file you use `*ngIf="isPopinOpen"` to show/hide the div. On same div you are calling `closePopin()` function on `click` event.

So, every time when you click on div the **isPopinOpen** variable change to false which hide the div that contains animation content.

> 1 - when I close the popin, the animation for sliding down does not work. It works only if I remove the line in comment.

The animation for sliding down is working perfectly. You aren't able to see the animation because as soon as you click on div that div hides because `isPopinOpen = false`

To solve the issue you need to use `setTimeout` function on `closeThePopin()` function in **app.component.ts** file or on `closePopin()` function in **popin.component.ts** file but not in both function.

I added `setTimeOut` function in **app.component.ts** file `closeThePopin()` function

```
closeThePopin() {
    // Added
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.isPopinOpen = false;
    }, 1000);
    this.isPopinAnimationActive = false;
}
```

Working Code Example: [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-animation-tdrdp?file=/src/app/popin/popin.component.ts)